# Can we stop the cronjob for 6-7 hrs each day?

Tags: cron

I have written the cronjob that runs each hour. Can we anyway stop the cronjob for 6-7 hrs each day ? Example : My cronjob runs a script each hour to fetch the traffic count on hourly basis. Now, during night, between 01:00 and 07:00 hrs,no transactions takes place and hence no count traffic. This can sometimes be misleading as if the system is down for 6 hrs each day (since the script sends an email if nothing is fetched for 1 hr). To improve that i want my cronjob to stop for 6 hrs between 01:00 and 07:0 hrs each day. So, can you please advise if we can do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just define which hours the cronjob *should* run?

```
 0 0,8-23 * * * /my/command
```

A [crontab entry](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/) like that would run at midnight and the hours between 0800 and 2300

Comment: Hi paul, Thanks :-) I have a linux server to work on, should the cron be written as 00 00,08-23 * * * /my/command OR the way you advised above ?

Comment: I don't think the leading zeroes make any difference

Comment: While i m trying to save the cron, it gives an error : crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.XXXX9hKsV2":4: bad command
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit? y
                                                                     im doing this : 00 0,1,9-23 * * * * /my/command [ here i want the cron to stop from 0200 to 0800.

Comment: ah, i got it. My fault. Thanks :-)